# Access flags in synchronized methods?

Tags: java, methods, synchronized

I was looking around some pdf's from a university class and I noticed this code part:

```
public class MyMemoryElements {
    private String x = "";

    public MyMemoryElements(String message){
        this.x = message;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object o){
        if(o instanceof MyMemoryElements ){
            MyMemoryElements tmp = (MyMemoryElements)o;
            if(tmp.toString().equalsIgnoreCase(this.x))
               return true;
            return false;
        }
        return false;

    }

    @Override
    public String toString(){
        return this.x;
   }
}
```

and the main code:

```
public class MainMemory {
   private Vector<MyMemoryElements> storage;
   private boolean canAccess = true;
   private int counter = -1;

   public MainMemory(){
       storage = new Vector<MyMemoryElements>();
   }

   public synchronized MyMemoryElements take(String s) {
       System.out.print("Method take has been invoked by "+s+". Element is:");
       while (!canAccess || storage.size()==counter+1) {
           try {
               wait();
           } catch (InterruptedException e) {}
       }
       canAccess = false;
       counter++;
       MyMemoryElements x = storage.elementAt(counter);
       try {
           Thread.sleep(10000);
       } catch (InterruptedException ex) {}
       notifyAll();
       System.out.println(x.toString());
       canAccess = true;
       return x;
   }

   public synchronized void update(MyMemoryElements element) {
       System.out.println("Producer is inserting element "+ element.toString());
       while (!canAccess) {
           try { 
               wait();
           } catch (InterruptedException e) {}
       }
       canAccess = false; 
       this.storage.add(element);
       notifyAll();
       canAccess = true;
   }
}
```

I cannot seem to understand the need for the `canAccess` variable considering the methods are synchronized (nor the reason the flag changes *after* `notifyAll` and not before)

**EDIT**: An additional question:
Is there any point in all of this code? I mean all it does is get and add something to the vector. Aren't those actions synchronized already on vectors? All this code just so we can get a few prints in?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I agree - there is no need for these extra checks, given that the methods are marked synchronized .

(Looks like someone wanted to be really, really sure that there were no synchronization issues.  :-)

Ironically, it could be argued that `canAccess` is not thread-safe.  So even without the methods being synchronized, this would not necessarily be a suitable alternative.

Comment: I agree too.. if we remove `synchronized` then even `canAccess` is not making it thread safe..Looks like the programmer started trying to do threadsafe implementation without `synchronized` but eventually ended up with `synchronized` and old code is still there.

Comment: Hmm, how would you make it thread-safe without `synchronized` using this approach (no locks, synchs etc.) other than, perhaps, making `canAccess` volatile? I understand perhaps in-between exiting the while loop and making `canAccess=false` there can be another thread doing the same? - Also, any thoughts on the secondary question about order of `notifyAll` and altering the flag?

Comment: @Jayto - yes, it seems that `canAccess = true` should come before `notifyAll()` - otherwise it seems that there would be a real potential for a deadlock here.

Comment: Alright. Perhaps final question: is there any point in all of this code? I mean all it does is get and add something to the vector. Aren't those actions synchronized already on vectors?

Comment: altering the flag after or before notifyAll doesn't matter, since those two actions are done inside a synchronized block, and the notified threads will only be able to read the new value of the flag after thay have acquired the lock, and thus after the notifying thread has released it.

Comment: @Jayto - Yes, it is.  Even if you used something else like `ArrayList`, you could always wrap it with `Collections.synchronizedList(...)`.

Comment: @JB Nizet correct, I should have made it clearer that I was wondering about their order in a non-synchronized fashion (as in, if the methods weren't tagged as `synchronized`)

Comment: @ziesemer, not sure I understood the answer, I was merely asking if all that code was needed to execute an add and a get function from a vector

Comment: Calling wait or notifyAll without synchronizing on the object will **always** throw an exception. You **must** hold the lock of the object to call these methods.

Comment: @Jayto - You are correct in that no, you don't need all of that extra code because Vector is synchronized.

Comment: This code is not commented, and I have not analized it sufficiently to understand what it does exactly, but it does more than storing and retrieving data from a Vector: it makes a consumer thread block until a producer thread has put an element into the vector.

Comment: @JB Nizet very true, I neglected that part. To wrap this up, you agree with ziesemer that the whole hasAccess approach is unneeded in this code, right?

Comment: Yes, I don't really understand the point of canAccess, since it's always set to false and then to true in the same synchronized block, without releasing the lock between the two modifications.